# Integrate a power of logarithm

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

Is there some way, how to solve this problem? 
$$
\int \ln^n(x) dx \text{,  where } n \in \mathbb{N} 
$$
I really don't know, what to do with $n$.

Comment: I'm assuming you want a reduction formula? If so, use integration by parts.

Comment: As an aside, $n!=(-1)^n~\displaystyle\int_0^1\ln^n(x).~$ See [History of the $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History) for more information.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use integration by part:
$$\begin{align} \int \ln^n(x)dx=\int(x)'\ln^n(x)dx \\ =x\ln^{n}(x)+\int x (\ln^{n}(x))dx \\ =x\ln^{n}(x)+\int x \frac{1}{x}n \ln^{n-1}(x)dx\\ =x\ln^{n}(x)+n\int \ln^{n-1}(x)dx \end{align}$$

Comment: So it should be repeated in series, till there isn't $\int \ln (x)  dx$?

Comment: Yes, it should be repeat.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Give $n$ concrete values: $n=0$, $n=1$ and $n=2$. See what you get (integration by parts will be useful) and how these three cases relate to each other. Then attack the "general" $n$ and hope you get a relation between $I_n$ and $I_{n-1}$, where $I_n = \int \ln^n(x) dx$.